# How to disable previous dates in Pikaday plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins, datepicker, pikaday

I've implemented Pikaday datepicker.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', '#date', function () { 
        var me = $("#date");   
        me.datepicker($.datepicker.regional[ "ru" ],{
            showOn: 'focus',
            altFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
            dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
            //minDate: '25.07.2017',
            //minDate: new Date('25.07.2017'),
            minDate: moment().toDate(),
            maxDate: '12.12.2020'
        }).focus();
        me.mask('99.99.9999');
    }).on('select', '#date', function () {
        var me = $("#date");
        //me.mask('99/99/9999');
    });
});
```

Now I cannot disable previous dates. Tried different varuiants, but result is the same. Fifth step: home-projects.ru/calculator

Sourse app/js/datepicker-ui-custom.js

Comment: can you create a fiddel example link of your problem? so that we can check and modify

Comment: BTW you can check documentation here:- http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/

Answer (score 1):

try this in datepicker parameter

```
minDate: new Date(),
```

Comment: are you try this one also `moment().toDate()` for date

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.